# USB-c R1/R2 configuration

Tags: usb-c, usb-host

I have a usb-c cable that plugs into a 4s lithium ion battery (DJI FPV goggle battery with proprietary cable.) The battery will only turn on if the usb-c plug (picture below) is plugged into it. I need to replicate this usb-c cable and my question is, is the R2 resistor the thing that creates the device/host recognition to allow the battery to turn on.

[image: USB-C connections]

I know it has to do with the usb-c plug because if I plug another charging cable into the battery it will not turn on.